# EF 5.0 Lookup Table Design Restricting Cascade Delete

Tags: sql, entity-framework-5

EF 5.0 Code First, SQL2012 localdb
I'm dveloping an application that has many lookup tables bound to comboboxes for input.  When the db is built EF finds all of the relationships and adds foreign keys where appropriate.  So now, as example, I have a table with a number of fields mapped to lookup table entries.  If I delete an entry in the table I don't want to cascade delete the mapped entry in the lookup table.  How do I protect the lookup table from cascade deletions?  I'm using DataAnnotations.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys work essentially the opposite of the way you seem to think they work. If you delete a row on the "many" side of a 1:M relationship, nothing happens to the table on the "one" side (the lookup table).

If you delete a row from the "one" side (the lookup table), then the delete should cascade to the tables on the "many" side. (As long as those tables have `ON DELETE CASCADE` as part of their foreign key references.)